# Office Custom UI: customization ignored and Error detected in XML ... 0x80070057 incorrect parameter

Tags: excel, ms-word, powerpoint, ms-office, ribbon

I tried to customize the Office ribbon for one of my Office documents, as explained [in chapter "To customize the Fluent UI by using Office Open XML Formats files"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202%28v=office.12%29).

It should theoretically add a new tab and one button, but when I open this document I always get this error (NB: I activated the Office option to see errors with Backstage view (File) > Options > Advanced Options > General > Show add-in user interface errors):

> Error detected in custom UI XML code ... Line 1 Column ... Error code 0x80070057 - Incorrect parameter.

Here is the popup containing the error message (NB: I have Office in French language): 
[image: Error detected in custom UI XML code (French)]

And the new tab does not show up at all.

It failed with an Excel document, but I also tried to do it with Word and PowerPoint, and got exactly the same error.

Here are the changes I did to `Classeur1.xlsx` to add the tab (renaming its suffix to .zip, manipulating its content, and renaming it back to .xlsx):

- In `_rels/.rels`, I added this line before added this line before `</Relationships>`:

  ```
  <Relationship Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/ui/extensibility"
       Target="customUI/customUI.xml" Id="customUIRelID"/>
  ```
- I created `customUI/customUI.xml`:

  ```
  <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <ribbon>
      <tabs>
        <tab id="MyTab" label="My Tab">
          <group id="MyGroup" label="My Group">
            <button id="MyButton" label="MyButton" onAction="MyMacro"/>
          </group>
        </tab>
      </tabs>
    </ribbon>
  </customUI>
  ```

NB: I know that the subroutine "MyMacro" must also be created and the Excel file is to be saved as type `.xlsm`, but I just want to propose the minimal case to reproduce, clicking the button is not the problem here.

My Excel, Word and PowerPoint versions: Office 365, Version 2008 (build 13127.20408 Office "click-and-go").

EDIT: here is the screenshot of version (NB: 2 days after my question, it has been upgraded automatically to version 2009 Build 13231.20262), and I haven't got the error now 
[image: Office subscription 365 PowerPoint version 2009][image: Office subscription 365 PowerPoint version 2009]

Comment: You can save yourself a LOT of trouble and work if you use one of several Office XML editors to add tabs/buttons/etc.  This is one that i've had good luck with:  https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor

Comment: @SteveRindsberg It's the tool I mentioned in the answer, but it doesn't prevent from choosing the bad option. I didn't even know that my Office version was 2008 because its interface and features look very modern. Maybe it's because it's part of Office 365. Anyway I'm not clear about what Office versioning really means nowadays (for instance wikipedia about [Office 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_2019): "Some features that had previously been restricted to Office 365 subscribers are available in this release").

Comment: One correction to your answer below: you can use the tool to insert code for either or BOTH namespaces, one for Office 2007, the other for all later versions, 2010 and onward, and all Office 365 (aka subscription) versions. As far as RibbonX code, that's about the only versioning issue.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I have the 365 subscription, but it's with Office 2008, only the namespace for Office 2007 is accepted, the one for 2010+ produces the error that has led to my question.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg I have added a comment in my answer because I am not sure to have tested correctly. Anyway probably it would help if someone gets the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

The error is that `<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">` is not valid for the version "2008" for subscription 365 -- I don't pretend that it's Office 2008, it's just what I saw, it's like now "2009" (see screenshot in my question) -- even if Steve Rindsberg doubts that versions 2008 and 2009 can appear, sorry to not have taken a screenshot -- hopefully I could find this screenshot mentioning a [version "2008" in this Windows blog post](https://www.tenforums.com/windows-10-news/165047-new-microsoft-365-current-channel-v2008-build-13127-20508-sept-22-a.html): 
[image: windows office with version 2008 !?]

Instead, I used the namespace `<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">` combined with relationship using the Relationship namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/ui/extensibility>`:

```
  <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon>
      <tabs>
        <tab id="MyTab" label="My Tab">
          <group id="MyGroup" label="My Group">
            <button id="MyButton" label="MyButton" onAction="MyMacro"/>
          </group>
        </tab>
      </tabs>
    </ribbon>
  </customUI>
```

Now, I can successfully see "my tab" when I open `Classeur1.xlsx`: 
[image: New custom tab in Excel ribbon]

## Reason

Ron de Bruin mentioned at https://rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm (**edit 2024: see [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20200801010314/https://rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm)**), while presenting the [Office RibbonX Editor](https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor), that one of the two versions must be selected:

- Insert Office 2010+ Custom UI Part
- Insert Office 2007 Custom UI Part

So I guess that there is a corresponding namespace according to the Office version (whatever it's under 365 subscription or not). Note that there is also a different namespace for `_rels\.rels` mentioned in [MS-CUSTOMUI] and [MS-CUSTOMUI2] Microsoft standards.

- 2010+ ([[MS-CUSTOMUI2]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui2/452a58ae-cb0a-4926-83f8-fb1cbaa6114c))

  - custom UI: `<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">`
  - Source relationship: `http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2007/relationships/ui/extensibility`
- 2007-2009 ([[MS-CUSTOMUI]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui/087c607c-5565-418c-8d31-772b91d93ff3))

  - custom UI: `<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">`
  - Source relationship: `http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/ui/extensibility`

(*) PS: I am not sure to have correctly tested if the combination of both namespaces for 2010 did work or not for my version "2008" with subscription 365. Steve has said in the comments that it should have worked because it's subscription 365. I can't test anymore for "2008" because my Office version was automatically upgraded to version 2009, and 2010 namespaces work.

Comment: Suggestion:  edit your post to fix the incorrect PPT versions. There's no version 2008 (at least not on Windows, and in Mac 2008 there's no VBA,so it's not relevant here). Versions that have the ribbon are 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016, 2019 and the Office 365/Microsoft 365 subscription versions. If your RibbonX code works in ANY version from 2010 onward, it'll work in all of them. The only special case is 2007.

Comment: I agree that Office 2008 and 2009 don't exist. Please tell me how to name the version "2008" and "2009" that I show in my screenshots -both in question and answer-?

Comment: If you're talking about the number you see when you look at File | Account, that's the Build version. For our purposes, that's unimportant. And for RibbonX purposes, all that matters is that you have Office 365.

Comment: Ron de Bruin has now removed the relevant content from his site. Archived versions of the linked URL: https://web.archive.org/web/20200801010314/https://rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm (edit queues are full so I can't edit it in.)